# How to close the window in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following link in my view that opens a changelog in a new page:

```
<%= link_to("Changelog", changelog_path, :target => "_blank") %>
```

In this changelog page I would like to create a link to close this changelog page.

What is the most appropriate way to do this ?

Is that possible to achieve this without Javascript ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use JavaScript for this. You can call `window.close()`, but this will prompt the user before closing the window, unless the window was opened from JavaScript with `window.open()`, so you will also need to use JavaScript for opening the window instead of a link with `target="_blank"`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, using the link I got the prompt window in Internet Explorer 8, but not in Firefox 4. Any ideas why ? Is that prompt window some kind of security issue ?

Comment: @Misha: One thing I can think of is that if arbitrary websites could close your main browser window, you might lose your session/history.